# Clicking on image does function supposed to be just for image's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a image gallery thing, and when you click on an image it opens up the image in full screen. Kind of like Facebook's theatre mode. I have it so when you click the images container it hides the container and the image. The problem is, the even also fires when I click on the image. And I don't want that.

Here's my code:

```
$("section ul li img").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");

    var image_src = $("section ul li img.clicked").prop("src");

    $("div.image-full").css({
        "visibility": "visible",
        "display": "block"
    });

    $("div.image-full img").prop("src", image_src);
});

$("div.image-full").on("click", function() {
    if($("div.image-full").css("cursor") == "pointer") {
        $("section ul li img.clicked").removeClass("clicked");

        var image_src;

        $("div.image-full").css({
            "visibility": "hidden",
            "display": "none"
        });

        $("div.image-full img").prop("src", "");
    }
});
```

I tried making it so if when I click and the cursor is a pointer it hides the container and the image but when it's just a regular cursor nothing fires. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation of the click event from the image to its parents by calling [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) on the event

```
$("div.image-full img").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're confused about what css `pointer:cursor;` means, since this is only a style.

If you're trying to capture a hover event, consider using `$.hover()` instead.  I've never seen someone try to check the css pointer ever in my life.

Comment: It was just an attempt. Nothing else seemed to work so I just tried it.

Comment: While this post is useful to the question author, it's not an answer. You should post it as a comment instead.

Answer (score -2):

Change this line:

```
$("div.image-full").on("click", function() {
```

to

```
$("div.image-full").click(function() {
```

Comment: you can use `on` to set an event listener, both those lines do the same thing

Comment: There's no difference in either one.

Comment: This answer also has nothing to do with the issue in the askers question, which is that the event is bubbling up the DOM tree.